# Cannot find dll entry-point. Run-time error 453

Tags: c#, vb6

Based on the challenge I asked on this forum through the link 
 [Consuming .NET dll in VB6 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465306/consuming-net-dll-in-vb6-application)
I was successfully able to consume my .NET dll within VB6 by registering the dll and it's .tlb files, referencing the tlb file within my application and using the code below:

```
Dim dObject as new DllName.ClassName
dObject.MethodName(filename)
```

The issue is I want to be able to use the code below

```
Declare Sub MethodNameLib "DllName" (ByVal ff As String) 
MethodName(filename)
```

However, I get the error "Run-time error 453: Cannot find dll entry-point. Please could any help as this is urgent?

Comment: Why do you want to use the `Declare` syntax? It doesn't offer any advantages, only disadvantages. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Microsoft link it will tell about how to develop a Dot Net DLL it will work with COM Objects(VB6) 
[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

and some other solutions here [link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t20314-use-net-created-dll-in-vb6.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `Declare ...` to call into COM (or .NET/COM Interop) libraries. These need to be created using the `Dim Obj As LibName.ClassName`, etc.

If you want to use `Declare ...` then you'll need to look at exposing individual methods from your .NET DLL in the export table using StdCall.